# Exclude file format from loop - .bat

Tags: batch-file

I am using a .bat script to convert some videos with ffmpeg, but I need tyo exclude any other files, like image files and other. How can I filter only the mp4 video files? In this case i am trying to exclude the png's, but not working. Thank you

```
dir | findstr /v /i "\.png$" 
for %%a in ("*.*") do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i watermark.png -filter_complex overlay "newfiles\%%~na.mp4"
pause
```

Comment: why not simply use ... in ("*.mp4") do ... ?

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%f in (*.mp4) do ffmpeg -i %%f .....
```